# Excel: find text anywhere in a table, return text in first column of the row

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a large table where:

In the first column are the stock shelf names.
In the rows next to the stock shelf names are columns of coded items on the shelf, in no particular order and the number of columns of coded items can vary greatly from row to row.

I want to look up a code anywhere in the table and return the stock shelf name that has that particular item.

I tried a variety of things like vlookup, index and match, offset, but I cant seem to get the combination and/or order right.

Thank you kindly for your help

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

You're right in using Index and Match, then combining with a couple other formulas.

Cell J1 is where you input the code you wish to find.

Cell J2 contains this formula:

```
=INDEX(A2:A5,MATCH(1,MMULT(--($B$2:$G$5=J1),TRANSPOSE(COLUMN($B$2:$G$5)^0)),0))
```

I'm receiving an error when adding a picture, so let me describe the table:

- Cells A2:A4 contain four shelf names (Red, Blue, Yellow and Orange).
- Range B2:G5 contain product ids. Some shelves have more than others.

Picture finally worked:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It's best show us a simple sample to show your item code.

Currently, I create a sample, for example, to find the shelf of "104", we can try formula: `=INDEX(A$1:A$4,SUMPRODUCT((H1=B$2:F$4)*ROW($2:$4)))`.

[image]